# displaying records from a php file via jquery;

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Ok I have this code

a script in my head.

```
function checkForm(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $('#de').hide()

    $.post('search.php', { name : search.searchinput.value() }, function(output) {
    $('#searchpage').html(output).show();
});

}
}
```

and this is the html part:

```
<form name="search" id="searchbox">
    <input name="searchinput" value="search item here..." type="text"   id="inputbox" onkeydown="checkForm(event);" onclick="clickclear(this, 'search item   here...')" onblur="clickrecall(this,'search item here...')"/><input id="submit" value=""   OnClick="checkForm(event);" type="submit"/>
</form>
<div id="searchpage"></div>
```

and this the php file where the script will pass the data into.

```
<?
$name= $_POST['name'];

$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

if(!$con)
{
die ('could not connect' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("juliver", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE title='$name' OR description='$name'     OR type='$name'"); 
$vv = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$vv .= "<div id='itemdiv2' class='gradient'>";
$vv .= "<div id='imgc'>".'<img src="Images/media/'.$row['name'].'" />'."<br/>";
$vv .= "<a href='#?w=700' id='".$row['id']."' rel='popup' class='poplight'>View full</a>"."</div>";
$vv .= "<div id='pdiva'>"."<p id='ittitle'>".$row['title']."</p>";
$vv .= "<p id='itdes'>".$row['description']."</p>";
$vv .= "<a href='".$row['link']."'>".$row['link']."</a>";
$vv .= "</div>"."</div>";
}

echo $vv;
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

here is the sceneraio, a user put a whatever text on the textbox name:'searchinput' and so whenever the user pressed the enter key the function checkForm(e) will execute and pass the data from the input field name:'searchinput' into the php file and then that php file will process the data into the mysql and see if the data that the script has pass into the php file is match to the mysql records and then if ever it match then the php file will pass that data back into the script and then the script will output the data to the #searchpage div.

Problem:

"all are not working" and the onclick function on the go button are not working"

please help, im stuck on this. thank you in advance.

Comment: If you developer, you should never say "not working". Show error and say returned this error or at least say "no action" happened. Try debug with Firebug on browser, and use debuggers on backside too. Also your codes are vulnerable to `sql injection`.

Comment: as you are using `<form>` tag, you do not need to check `(e.keyCode == 13)` because the form will get submitted as soon as you hit enter. In addition to it, check whether the ajax request is working or not using firebug.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is a website called [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Paste your codes in the website and then paste the URL here. It makes your post a lot more readable.

Now, here if you are using jQuery, then why are you relying on onkeydown and onclick events? Its better to use jQuery's live function.
I have changed your code. Have a look at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MtnEe/). You can use live function for other events like onclick,onfocus,onblur,etc. It makes your HTML code much more cleaner and readable.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using load instead of post 
(And remove the form tag or change input to textarea or else hitting enter will submit your form)

```
$('#inputbox').keypress(function(event){
 var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
 if(keycode == '13')
  {
    $('div#searchpage').load('search.php',{name: $(this).val()});   
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to stop the form from submitting the data, use something like 
onsubmit="return (checkForm(e))"

and double check for syntax errors, for example you have missed a Semicolon at this line
$('#de').hide()